# Display HTML page content into Jenkins email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I'm trying to display HTML page content into the body of the Jenkins email, i added the following code to the default content section in Editable Email plugin:

```
${FILE,path="/target/surefire-reports/html/index.html"}
```

also i tried to add the following code to Pre-send Script in the Email plugin:

```
def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("HealthTestResults.html")
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html");
```

both of the two way didn't work and i'm still receiving empty mails.

Answer (score 0):

What about have a try with DSL, if you don't bother have one more Jenkins job

You can:

1. Add a new build step "Process Job DSLs" (You will need [Job DSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl))
2. Add this Groovy script to "Use the provided DSL script" field

> Groovy script

```
job(jobname_to_your_email_job) {
  publishers {
    extendedEmail {
      recipientList(your_email_list)
      defaultSubject(your_subject)
      defaultContent(your_default_content)
      contentType('text/html')
      triggers {
        always {
          subject(your_subject)
          //read your html file and put it in the content field
          content(readFileFromWorkspace(path_to_your_html_file))
          sendTo {
            recipientList()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//This will put your email job to the build queue so your email job will run automatically
queue("Email Report")
```

And of course, you can customize this part according to the [Docs](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.extendedEmail)

Comment: could you go check the job created by this groovy script to see the content field of "editable email" in the post-build step? Is it empty or not?

Comment: I used the above mentioned Groovy script.I checked in the job created by groovy script. The content field contains html script... But receiving empty mails only

Answer (score 0):

Tried `${FILE,path="target/surefire-reports/html/index.html"}`? ie without the /